# How to integrate this (standard Gaussian RV)?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am given this integration result ($y$ is a standard, gaussian random variable, $\gamma$ is a constant).

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{\gamma}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\gamma}{2+\gamma}}$$

I don't understand how to arrive at this result.

What I have is this.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-2y^2-\gamma y^2}{2\gamma}}dy = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\Big(e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}\Big)^{\frac{2+\gamma}{\gamma}}dy$$

How do I integrate this?

Comment: Take care: $e^{a+b}\neq(e^{a})^b=e^{ab}$

Comment: What you have to do is to factor $y^2$: $\exp(\frac{-2y^2-\gamma y^2}{2\gamma})=\exp\left(-\frac{2+\gamma}{\gamma}\frac{y^2}{2}\right)$ and make an appropriate change of variable $y \rightarrow Y$ in order to find back the integral of $\exp\left(-\frac{Y^2}{2}\right)$

Comment: Notice:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{\gamma}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}\text{d}y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left[-\frac{y^2(2+\gamma)}{2\gamma}\right]\text{d}y$$

Comment: What you have to do is to factor $y^2$: $\exp(\frac{-2y^2-\gamma y^2}{2\gamma})=\exp\left(-\frac{2+\gamma}{\gamma}\frac{y^2}{2}\right)$ and make an appropriate change of variable $y \rightarrow Y$ in order to find back the integral of $\exp\left(-\frac{Y^2}{2}\right)$.

Comment: Thanks to both for the suggestion to factor out $y^2$. I understand out to get the result now.